# How to filter data by LINQ when data is coming from CSV file

Tags: c#, linq, csv

here i am giving a idea how my csv file has data

```
Call start       Call duration    Ring duration       Direction     Is_Internal   Continuation    Party1Name
----------      -------------     -------------       ---------     -----------  ------------    -----------   
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              1             1             ACC
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             ACC
09-06-15 11:27    0:00:06           0                   )              0             1             Sales
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             ACC
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              1             0             Suzzy
09-06-15 03:27    0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             Suzzy
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             ACC
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   O              0             0             Sales
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              1             1             ACC
09-06-15 12:27    0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             Matt
09-06-15 10:27    0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             VM Channel
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   )              0             0             VM Channel
09-06-15 7:27     0:00:06           0                   I              0             1             Voice Mail
```

Now i want to show employee wise data like below

```
CSR Name       Incomming      outgoing    call transfer
--------       ----------     --------    -------------
ACC               10               12           11
SALES             05               06           02
Suzy              7                 5            5
Matt              2                 2            2
```

my condition would be 
1) for incoming direction has to be I and for outgoing direction will be O
2) employee name VM Channel and Voice mail will not be consider

and more

i am not good in linq and that is why posting this question for help. i have linq query sample which is bit similar but still no idea what to rectify in it or add to get my desired out put.

### here is linq code

```
void Main()
{
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");   
    var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

    //int iDir = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I');
    var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
    {
                CSRName =   data[12],
                Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "I"),
                outgoing = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "O")
    }).ToList();
    users.Dump();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int outgoing;
    public int Incomming;
    public int calltransfer;
}
```

how to remove employee name VM Channel and Voice mail from the result. in sql we can use not like and not in clause but what similar things available in linq ?

how to fetch employee name wise data

```
CSRName = data[12],
Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "I")
```

if this line `CSRName = data[12]` return suzy then suzy related incoming data will be stored in `Incomming` variable. how to achieve it.

just wonder if anyone can help with linq query.

Comment: Your question boils down to "How can I filter with LINQ?". What have you tried so far?

Comment: This might help you: [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library).

Comment: i want to achieve it with LINQ..........no 3rd party please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried a bit aground and got the code below.
But i don't know how much of this works because i am not that good of LINQ.
If this does not work you may be able to work with my solution and make a better one :)

```
var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

// i am assuming that line[7] is the Party1Name Column
// now you have a (sorted) group with n "members" (ACC, Sales, ..., n )
var groupOfUser = from line in csvLinesData 
                  group line by line[7] into newGroup 
                  orderby newGroup.Key 
                  select newGroup;

// The Key of your userOfGrp is the Name e.g. "ACC"
// i am assuming that x[4] is the direction Column
// I count all I or O and put them into the new User
var user = (from userOfGrp in groupOfUser
            select
                new User()
                    {
                        CSRName = userOfGrp.Key,
                        Incomming = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "I"),
                        Outgoing = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "O")
                    }).ToList();
```

the group queue is copied from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx). You may have a look into this

But why do you want LINQ? Other solutions can be great too!

Comment: this is missing in linq query. "how to remove employee name VM Channel and Voice mail from the result. in sql we can use not like and not in clause but what similar things available in linq ?"  where is code to execule CSR Name like "Voice Mail" and start with "VM" ?

Comment: can u write second set of answer where you write the same query using lamda.

Comment: "in LINQ", this is LINQ :D
but i could look if i can do it in query + lamda - tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jens who help me to construct the below linq query. i post my full code which is working fine. thanks

```
void Main()
{
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

// i am assuming that line[7] is the Party1Name Column
// now you have a (sorted) group with n "members" (ACC, Sales, ..., n )
var groupOfUser = from line in csvLinesData 
                  where  !line[12].Contains("VM") && !line[12].Contains("Voice Mail")
                  group line by line[12] into newGroup 
                  orderby newGroup.Key 
                  select newGroup;

// The Key of your userOfGrp is the Name e.g. "ACC"
// i am assuming that x[4] is the direction Column
// I count all I or O and put them into the new User
var user = (from userOfGrp in groupOfUser
            select
                new User()
                    {
                        CSRName = userOfGrp.Key,
                        Incomming = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "I"),
                        Outgoing = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "O")
                    }).ToList();
                    user.Dump();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int Outgoing;
    public int Incomming;
    public int calltransfer;
}
```